# Convert string to dictionary with multiple values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This folowing returns 
    `{'Name': 'Value1'}` but I am looking for `{'Name': 'Value1', 'Value2'}`. Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

```
a = ["Name"]
b = "Value1 Value2"
c=b.split()
d=dict(zip(a, c))
```

Comment: Do you mean that `Name` should be the key for a list with `Value1` and `Value2` in it, or something else?

Comment: Yes though I am not completely sure it is what I need for the next step but you've hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% how you want to build this dict, mainly because your code does not return `{'Name': 'V'}`, it returns `{'Name': 'Value1'}`.

Dictionaries store one-to-one mappings between keys and values. That means that an entry such as `{'Name': 'Value1', 'Value2'}` would not be valid in a dictionary.

The workaround that most people use (and what you appear to be trying to do based on your code) is to store lists as values instead.  However, your code misuses the `zip()` builtin.  One thing that would work would be

```
a = ["Name"]
b = "Value1 Value2"
c=b.split()
d=dict(zip(a,[c]))  # Zip two single-element lists instead of zipping 
                    # lists of different size
```

but as I said before, I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for.  I hope it helps though!

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary is not correctly formatted. You should have a tuple of values as a value of the dictionary:

```
a = ["name"]
b = [("Value1", "Value2")]
d = dict(zip(a,b))
```

Comment: Sorry Pablo Martinez, your answer was right but I edited my query.

Comment: I don't get what you expect as a result of your query `{'Name': 'Value1', 'Value2'}` is not a valid dictionary. A key must point to a single value, and you have two values, You need to pack them both to add them to a dictionary as I've shown in my code.